# UIViewAnimation causes Implicit conversion from enumeration type

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm getting this warning

Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIViewAnimationCurve' to different enumeration type 'UIViewAnimationTransition'

from the last line in this code

```
if (((UIView*)[[slideViews subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).frame.origin.x > SLIDE_VIEWS_MINUS_X_POSITION) {
    UIView* tempRight2View =[[slideViews subviews] objectAtIndex:[[slideViews subviews] count]-1];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ALIGN_TO_MINIMENU" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut forView:viewAtLeft cache:YES];
```

I'm adapting code from StackScrollView, any know how to "explicitly" convert?

TIA

Comment: Method `[UIView beginAnimations:context:]` is deprecated and you shouldn't used it any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a different set of enum: there you must put one of the UIViewAnimationTransition

```
typedef enum {
UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown} UIViewAnimationTransition;
```

while you are using one of UIViewAnimationCurve:

```
typedef enum {
UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut,
UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn,
UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut,
UIViewAnimationCurveLinear} UIViewAnimationCurve
```

they are still all integer but from different groups of constants

Answer (score 0):

All enums are integers.

The method your calling takes a `UIViewAnimationTransition`.

```
+ (void)setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)transition 
                       forView:(UIView *)view 
                         cache:(BOOL)cache;
```

you're setting it to one of the values defined by `UIViewAnimationCurve`.